# loop within a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying to run a loop inside a loop to get some valid dates but doesnt seem to work fine. my sample data is like

these are valid days
`[ 'Monday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Sunday' ]`

and these are valid dates

```
[ Sun Oct 09 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Mon Oct 10 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Tue Oct 11 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Wed Oct 12 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Thu Oct 13 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Fri Oct 14 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Sat Oct 15 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Sun Oct 16 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time) ]
```

What I want to do is: find only those dates on which are equal to vaid days

What am doing is:

```
_valid_dates = (dates, days) ->
  validDates = dates
  dates.forEach (date) ->
    days.forEach (day) ->
      if moment_strf(date).strftime("%A") != day
        validDates.remove date
      else
        console.log "Am valid day", moment_strf(date).strftime("%A")

  validDates
```

But the results are not coming as I am expecting. According to data the remaining dates should be

```
[ Sun Oct 09 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Mon Oct 10 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Thu Oct 13 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Fri Oct 14 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time),
  Sun Oct 16 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time) ]
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What are `moment_strf` and `validDates.remove`?

Comment: How many records you have in your result set? Is it always the same or not? How your results are populated?

Comment: `validDates = dates` is a shallow copy (i.e. only the reference is copied, not what it points to) so perhaps you're falling into the old "deleting from an array while iterating over it" trap. You'd probably be better off making a separate list of the things you want and leaving the arguments alone.

Comment: Moment strf is being adopted from momentjs. And .romove is a method to remove array with value

Comment: I asked because I couldn't find any documentation for these two functions anywhere. Anyway, if @muistooshort's recommendation doesn't work, you should probably delve into these functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it simply using only javascript:

Instead of taking full names in day array you can use 0-6 for days and then

```
    //sunday=0,monday=1 ....saturday=6
     var days=[1,4,5,0];
     var result_arr=[]; // required array for result
     for(date in dates)
     {
        if(days.indexOf(new Date(date).getDay())!=-1)
         {
             result_arr.push(date);
         }
      }
```

Comment: @JunaidFarooq, I think what you want to get by above code is valid dates(which have days available in days array [ 'Monday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Sunday' ]), so if i understood correct my code will work correctly and if your question is different please clear it. Thankyou